# how can i solve my build error because of gradle?

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

Here is the problem: I manually upgrade my gradle version from 7.4 to 7.6 in gradle-wrapper properties section. Everything works fine but when i create a new project gradle version downgrading 7.4 automatically. How can i set gradle version to 7.6 permanently?

Comment: gradle wrapper settings is "PER PROJECT" ; it has no affect outside the project. if you create a new project elsewhere - it will default to you local gradle or IDE defaults.

Comment: how can i change default gradle version in VScode?